# avoiding overuse of consensus protocols in a distributed system

Tags: distributed-computing, paxos

I'm new to distributed systems, and I'm reading about "simple Paxos". It creates a lot of chatter and I'm thinking about performance implications.

Let's say you're building a globally-distributed database, with several small-ish clusters located in different locations. It seems important to minimize the amount of cross-site communication.

1. What are the decisions you definitely need to use consensus for? The only one I thought of for sure was deciding whether to add or remove a node (or set of nodes?) from the network. It seems like this is necessary for vector clocks to work. Another I was less sure about was deciding on an ordering for writes to the same location, but should this be done by a leader which is elected via Paxos?
2. It would be nice to avoid having *all* nodes in the system making decisions together. Could a few nodes at each local cluster participate in cross-cluster decisions, and all local nodes communicate using a local Paxos to determine local answers to cross-site questions? The latency would be the same assuming the network is not saturated, but the cross-site network traffic would be much lighter.
3. Let's say you can split your database's tables along rows, and assign each subset of rows to a subset of nodes. Is it normal to elect a set of nodes to contain each subset of the data using Paxos across all machines in the system, and then only run Paxos between those nodes for all operations dealing with that subset of data?

And a catch-all: are there any other design-related or algorithmic optimizations people are doing to address this?

Comment: One can use zookeeper as a service (much like Google uses chubby as a service) to handle the consistency of core config and minimal shared meta data. As you suggest it can be cluster membership or which business keys are processed on which server in a loose federation of servers not a tight knit cluster. See http://curator.apache.org/ for the standard patterns from which you can build a looser federation of processing around a strongly consistent core locking/consistency service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good questions, and good insights!

> It creates a lot of chatter and I'm thinking about performance implications.
>
> Let's say you're building a globally-distributed database, with several small-ish clusters located in different locations. It seems important to minimize the amount of cross-site communication.
>
> What are the decisions you definitely need to use consensus for? The only one I thought of for sure was deciding whether to add or remove a node (or set of nodes?) from the network. It seems like this is necessary for vector clocks to work. Another I was less sure about was deciding on an ordering for writes to the same location, but should this be done by a leader which is elected via Paxos?

Yes, performance is a problem that my team had seen in practice as well. We maintain a consistent database & distributed lock manager; and orignally used Paxos for all writes, some reads and cluster membership updates.

Here are some of the optimizations we did:

- As much as possible, nodes sent the transitions to a Distinguished Proposer/Learner (elected via Paxos), which

  - decided on write ordering, and
  - batched transitions while waiting for the response from the prior instance. (But batching too much also caused problems.)
- We had considered using multi-paxos but we ended up doing something cooler (see below).

With these optimizations, we were still hurting for performance, so we split our server into three layers. The bottom layer is Paxos; it does what you suggest; viz. merely decides the node membership of the middle layer. The middle layer is a custom-in-house-high-speed chain consensus protocol, which does consensus & ordering for the DB. (BTW, chain-consensus can be viewed as Vertical Paxos.) The top layer now just maintains the database/locks & client connections. This design has lead to several orders of magnitude latency and throughput improvement.

---

> It would be nice to avoid having all nodes in the system making decisions together. Could a few nodes at each local cluster participate in cross-cluster decisions, and all local nodes communicate using a local Paxos to determine local answers to cross-site questions? The latency would be the same assuming the network is not saturated, but the cross-site network traffic would be much lighter.
>
> Let's say you can split your database's tables along rows, and assign each subset of rows to a subset of nodes. Is it normal to elect a set of nodes to contain each subset of the data using Paxos across all machines in the system, and then only run Paxos between those nodes for all operations dealing with that subset of data?

These two together remind me of the [Google Spanner paper](http://research.google.com/archive/spanner.html). If you skip over the parts about time, it's essentially doing [2PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) globally and Paxos on the shards. (IIRC.)

Comment: Sweet, just what I was hoping to learn! The Spanner paper is very good reading as well.

Comment: By the way, I'm having trouble finding info on "chain consensus protocols" - do you have a link? (I read about Vertical Paxos instead but didn't want to miss something by accident.)